# /Android Studio emulator via ADB and extract token of specified application

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I'm looking for solution to export token from logged in account on my emulator. I've researched all ADB commands over google but I don't see any solution to fix this.

Maybe someone found way to do it? is it stored somewhere in application? or need extract request??